# How to get which folders are currently open in explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer, batch, window, task-manager, files-folders

The folders which are open are shown in taskmanager. Perhaps there is a way to access this information with batch or powershell or third party command-line?

[image: explorer-taskmanager.webp]

I have also enabled the **Restore previous folder windows at logon** option...
[image: S5032-Folder-Options.webp]

So I wonder where the paths of the previously open folder windows is saved.. in regedit? Or in a temporary file somewhere?

Comment: duplicate: [Get Explorer's children in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48084216/995714)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't know where folders are saved at shutdownn, but to get info on open folders in **PowerShell**,use the [shell.application](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell) COM object:

```
@((New-Object -com shell.application).Windows()).Document.Folder | select Title , { $_.Self.Path }
```

### Sample Output

```
PS C:\...\keith>@((New-Object -com shell.application).Windows()).Document.Folder | select Title , { $_.Self.Path }

Title         $_.Self.Path
-----        --------------
This PC      ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
Quick access ::{679F85CB-0220-4080-B29B-5540CC05AAB6}
Windows (C:) C:\
SendTo       C:\Users\keith\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
```

- [Windows()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-windows) method

  - [ShellWindows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shellwindows) object

    - [Window](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752084(v=vs.85)) ( InternetExplorer object )

      - [Document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752052(v=vs.85)) property

        - [Folder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder) object

          - [Self ( FolderItem object )](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folderitem)

---

To get humann-friendly names for virtual folders as well as see the full namespace path, you can define a recursive function that gives you the full path (rooted in the virtual Desktop):

```
Function NSPath ($oFldr)
{
    If ($oFldr.ParentFolder )
    {
        '{0}\{1}'-f (NSPath $oFldr.ParentFolder), $oFldr.Title
    }
    Else
    {
        '\' # or $oFldr.Title
    }
}
```

Then use the function like so:

```
@((New-Object -com shell.application).Windows()).Document.Folder | %{ NSPath $_ }
```

### OUtput:

```
PS C:\...\keith>@($shell.Windows()).Document.Folder | %{ NSPath $_ }
\\This PC
\\Quick access
\\Keith Miller\Documents
\\This PC\Documents
\\This PC\Windows (C:)\Users\keith\Documents
```

To make it easy to use from within batch, add the function to your PowerShell profile like so:

```
@'
New-Object -com shell.application
Function NSPath ($oFldr)
{
    If ($oFldr.ParentFolder )
    {
        '{0}\{1}'-f (NSPath $oFldr.ParentFolder), $oFldr.Title
    }
    Else
    {
        '\' # or $oFldr.Title
    }
}
'@ | add-content $PROFILE
```

and then both the function `NSPath` and the COM object `$Shell` are available for use whenever you launch **PowerShell**.

Comment: Now the question is.. how do I cut this into segments and save each `folder path` alone into a text list?

Comment: Please clarify. Just the folder paths? `@((New-Object -com shell.application).Windows()).Document.Folder.Self.Path`. Want that list on the clipboard? add  `  | Out-String | Set-Clipboard ` to the command. To a file? Add ` | Set-Content 'C:\Path\To\File.txt' ` .

Comment: This is what I wanted --> `powershell  @^(^(New-Object -com shell.application^).Windows^(^)^).Document.Folder.Self.Path >> openfolderspaths.txt`

Comment: Cool. If you're not using the paths for shell operations, "::{CLSID}" may not be the most useful form. You can add the `NSPath` function to your **PowerShell** profile and then it would be available to give you human-friendly paths for virtual folders.

Comment: See edited answer for function. I know nothing of batch syntax, I alwasys used VBScript before PowerShell. What do you need from batch that you can't get from PPowerShell?